# generating preview of BMP Image

Tags: apache-flex, canvas, loader, bitmapdata, bmp

I am working on a Media up-loader which uploads images to Server. Before start upload file i want to show small thumbnail of Image.

I used Loader class to load image selected by user & used Canvas to draw image on it.

This works fine with images like jpg & png.

But for bmp file loader class doesn't work.

Is there anyway to load bmp image in Flex & Convert it to BitmapData ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test the example, but you could try this:
[Parsing and displaying BMP files via ActionScript](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/09/17/parsing-and-displaying-bmp-files-via-actionscript/)
And read the comments under the article, there are some links as well.