# Can Flex Application upload and Display .bmp Files at runtime?

Tags: apache-flex, image-uploading, bmp

I am trying to upload images in my Flex tool.
Using mx.controls.Image class, I could load and display the JPG / GIF / PNG files at runtime. 
But I'm not able to upload the BMP files with the Image class (or control); what I get is only broken-image icon. It gives Error after selecting image with .bmp extension. If i continue then it upload the image but display it as Broken Image.

[image: Error is this.]

I don't understand why BMP files are displaying as broken image.

Comment: Does [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761882/bitmap-image-in-flex) help?

Comment: @aljipa: Sorry but this would not help me. I'm uploading images dynamically. On browse Button File Reference is getting file filter.
In file filter, I already defined all image type extension. But its not working for .bmp file.

Comment: Try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572535/generating-preview-of-bmp-image

Comment: Try this as well: ??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106195/loading-bmp-and-tiff-file-in-flash-10-using-loader